# /usr/sbin/mysqld taking 800% CPU and can't find the solution i read several topics, centos 7 cpanel

Tags: mysql, mariadb

First of all i don't have very advanced experience with linux, only for what i needed for now, i am really annoyed and don't know what to do, i read about this in other several topics but it dosent help at all

[mysqld taking 800% CPU since traffic increased on my site, how to fix](https://serverfault.com/questions/908941/mysqld-taking-800-cpu-since-traffic-increased-on-my-site-how-to-fix)

So the problem is this:

[HIGH CPU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvGEG.png)

As you can see the my mysql process takes 800% CPU after some time, and there i don't know if it's an new attack method or something but i am using cpanel with cpnginx and i had normal site working for few months, it started to happen from a week, i didin't see anything from my error log that can prevent this happening...

The only thing i can do to put the mysql down from eating my 800% CPU is restarting the dedicated server, when i kill the process and comes back again, its still 800% CPU, sometimes 600%, jumping from 500% to 850% CPU, so all my databases are down and my 2 domains are not accessable because they need SQL to run.

There is my configuration file from /etc/my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
long_query_time=0.1
performance_schema=on

# ERROR LOGI
log-error=/var/lib/mysql/h2k.how2kill.pl.err

# GENERAL
wait_timeout=1000
max_connections=200
interactive_timeout=30
tmp_disk_table_size=1G
max_heap_table_size = 32M
tmp_table_size=200M
join_buffer_size=200M
# INNODB
innodb_buffer_pool_size=3GB
innodb_log_file_size=384M
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=3
innodb_lru_scan_depth=100
innodb_log_buffer_size=1G
innodb_log_file_size=4G
innodb_io_capacity=1000
innodb_change_buffer_max_size=10
innodb_file_per_table=1
# CACHE
table_open_cache=128
query_cache_type=0
query_cache_limit=128M
query_cache_min_res_unit = 2K
query_cache_size=0
thread_cache_size=100
key_buffer_size=256M
sort_buffer_size=2M
```

Normally my site should work like this:

[NORMAL CPU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1O7r.png)

It always worked like this but after few hours it jumps up to fecking 800% and i can't do anything...

I runned mysqltuner, and do some improvments in mysql but still doesent help at all..

Please help me, i appreciate all help because i try to resolve this problem for like 40 hours.

Comment: According to the screenshot, *most* of your CPU ressources are consumed by java processes. Additionally, it would be very helpful to see [what query](https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/mysql/enabling-the-slow-query-log-in-mysql) is causing this load, because mysql (usually) does not consume any CPU without doing anything.

Comment: I actually disabled everything with java today and still same problem occured, i needed to restart my dedicated server to make it work ;/

Comment: How about *enabling* SlowQuery logging, like the comment says? You will find a step-by-step-guide in the link.

Comment: I did enable it for now @bjoster , but now my site is working fine from what i can see, maybe in few hours or night hours it will happen again so i can post the results, because when its 800% CPU, its too hard to put any commands into my dedicated server.

Comment: Good; as long as you have configured a logfile, too, you can post the query later when the consol eis back. If you want to protect your shell from beeing destroyed by mysql, you can always denice the process(es).

Comment: I don't understand too much about protecting my shell, is there any way that i can have some better contanct method with you and you help me solve that problem?
If you are very very busy man i am willing to pay, but actually i don't have much experience with mariadb or mysql, i only read the forums like this..

Comment: We *do* offer commercial support, but let's try severfault first. Post your slowlogs when done and we will find an answer.

Comment: @bjoster it happened again just right now, i have the log now from the file, its very large, how can i send you that so you can help me?

Comment: Look at it and post the relevant parts. It *should* be more or less self explainable.

Comment: @bjoster   

Okey so i post my logs from the slow log but this file have around 4700000 lines so i post around the latest logs file.

https://pastebin.com/raw/0XzH1gY7

Comment: and another logs :(
https://pastebin.com/raw/CY1NpTuD
@bjoster

Comment: Is this really part of a query?  `WHERE  member_group_id != member_group_id NOT IN(94,96)`?  Although it compiles, it does not make sense.

Comment: Something is wrong with both slowlogs that you posted.

Comment: Yes it is, everything is part of the query, i am using invision community suite for 2 domains, but i was working fine anyway for the past 4 months, since 2 weeks its happening... @RickJames

Comment: It is *very* likely, that this query (`WHERE member_group_id != member_group_id ...`) is beein run in a loop. Every hit on the site starts a loop, when reached enough hits those loops will kill your ressources.

Comment: Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com and share the links.
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis.

Comment: If you have cloudlinux, you can install dbgovernor, then you will see which cpanel user exceed CPU limit in the log.

Comment: @KubaWitek Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com and share the links. Text results of: B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; after minimum 24 hours UPTIME C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - ulimit -a for a linux/unix list of limits, iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, for server workload tuning analysis.

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE `core_sys_lang_words` ADD INDEX(lang_id, word_key);

ALTER TABLE `bimchatbox_chat` ADD INDEX(user, `time`);
```

This will be mis-parsed:

```
WHERE  'member_group_id' != `member_group_id` NOT IN(94,96)
```

What do you want it to mean?

Comment: How can i apply that?

Comment: That is effectively `('x' != 'x') NOT IN (...)`  The first part is always `FALSE`, which is the same as `0`.  So this WHERE always fails.  What did you _want_ there?

Comment: (I found that several times in the slowlog)

Comment: I can't tell you that actually, i don't know the queries from Invision Community Suite but as i said it was working fine, like for this moment right know, both sites are working normally, i get only 3% on CPU max from 2 websites, in the morning maybe 12 PM, or 3 PM, out of nowhere there will be probably 800% again CPU USAGE, only because of the mysql, is there anything wrong my my.cnf settings? I did modernize them couple of times, they seems to be okey, i just need to get it sorted out, please help me, if someone is able to

Comment: I can't help you with why it worked, then broke, except to suggest this strange expression.  Did the version of Invision change?  Maybe they broke something?

Comment: I use for all sites the same version, the latest one, funny that i don't get any slow logs from this site: how2kill.pl but only on my second one: csowicze.pl
But its a same forum software, its just a bit of bullshit to me, that something like this is happening ;/

Comment: And when i actually kill the mysql and restart it, still is 800%, when i reboot, it work for a while.

Comment: Update, this: WHERE 'member_group_id' != `member_group_id` NOT IN(94,96)
This plugin in IPS has been disabled, so there is no logs from this one anymore, but it stills is around 400% or 300%, so databases are still not accessable, so maybe you can tell me something about other logs.

Comment: If the slowlog file does not exist, then it is not configured the same.  If it exists but has no statements, then check `long_query_time`.

Comment: See if you can get another slowlog output.  Now that the NOT IN is gone, the 'real' problem may be easier to find.  Have you added those indexes I suggested?

Comment: Tell me how can i add those indexes and tell me step by step what can i do, so i can give you full logs or anything else that will help you finding the problem in my case.

Comment: @KubaWitek - see addition.

Comment: Okey i appreciate the SQL commands, now i added those indexes, i dont know how this can help me, tell me how can i set up slow-query logs in my.cnf propery so i can give you better output.
And can you explain me what does indexes do actually?

Comment: @KubaWitek - Look for some basic explanations of indexes.  Some of the links of my [_Cookbook_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) are basic.

Comment: Okey i did what you asked me for, tell me can you set  up slow-query logs propery, if possible ;)
Thank you :D

Comment: @KubaWitek - http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog

Answer (score 1):

Okey guys after i deleted application that uses query (WHERE member_group_id != member_group_id ...)

I didint have my websites shutdown for around 1 day and 8 hours, so there is improvment.

I want to thank very much to Rick and bjoster for help, i really appreciate it and you really saved a lot of my time.

Now because i modify my configuration file many many many times, i want someone who is very experienced with mysql, to modify my.cnf configuration that would be perfect for my dedicated server.

Answer (score 0):

As Rick said, this is obviously problem with the *query* and/or the code genreating that queries, *not* with the server itself.

Answer (score 0):

Kuba Witek, 800% busy for a short time might be tolerable.  Divide your CPU busy (reported by TOP) by core count for effective system busy.  To determine your core count, from LX Command Prompt, iostat -xm 5 3 and press enter will usually reveal your core count. For instance 800/12 means your CPU was busy 66% of the time observed.  If it stays pegged at 800% for an hour, you need to find out why.  15 seconds of General Log would probably give you some valuable clues.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions for your my.cnf [mysqld] section

```
tmp_table_size=128M  # from 200M to stay under 1% RAM
max_heap_table_size=128M  # from 32M normally matched to tmp_table_size
join_buffer_size=1M  # from 200M per connection RAM requested for function
innodb_log_file_size=384M  # to be REMOVED, there is another later for 4G
innodb_log_buffer_size=512M  # from 1G - you have only 16G of RAM
query_cache_limit=0  # from 128M because QC is OFF to conserve RAM
query_cache_min_res_unit=512  # from 2K to conserve RAM if you ever turn on QC
tmp_disk_table_size=1G  # research in depth, not a variable in 5.7 or 8.0 I can find.
```

What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @KubaWitek     Were any these suggestions implemented?  Any feedback on results - positive or negative?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

did you ever use mytop?
It would be helfpull too.

Just as question, what says top, when yxou have 800% Usage?
What about IOWAit, swap usage?

free -m

on mysql, maybe execute:

mysql> show engine innodb status \G;

Do you have DB Locks? Concurrent access on same data rows?
Maybe also have a look on the myql processes they are running:

mysql> show full processlist;

or better way:

```
mysql> select NAME, PROCESSLIST_STATE, PROCESSLIST_INFO,PROCESSLIST_TIME  from performance_schema.threads where TYPE = 'FOREGROUND' and PROCESSLIST_STATE NOT like 'sleep' ;
```

Lets start with that.

Whe you find some long running processes: You could analyyse usage of index and what the query exactly does (it's cost) by explain;

```
explain select * from mysql.user;
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------+
| id   | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra |
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | user  | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    7 |       |
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 websites with VPS with Debian 10, with Lenity for lack of RAM .. I think, but I tried to reduce swappiness from 60 to 10

But it has not improved much

And here is a bit the result of the HTOP .. of the free .M

Something else could do?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZF5Uu.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGVgG.png)